# Как объявить массив строк, нужно для решения этой задачи:

Tags: c, c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int i;
int q;

using namespace std;

char *s;

main ()  {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus");
    cout<<"Исходный текст на английском языке записан в нескольких строчек одинаковой длины. Заменить все встречающиеся окончания ING на ED и уплотнить текст.\n";
    cout<<"Введите латинские символы строки \n";
    s = new char [100];
    gets (s);
    i = strlen (s);
    if (i>0) {
        while (i>0) {
            if  (i>2) {
                if (s[i]=='g' && s[i-1]=='n' && s[i-2]=='i') {
                    s[i]=' ';
                    s[i-1]='d';
            s[i-2]='e';} }
            i--;
        }
        int j;
        for (i=0;i<strlen (s);i++) {
            while (s[i]==' ' && s[i+1]==' ')
            {j=i;
                for(j;j<strlen (s);j++)
            s[j+1]=s[j+2];}
        }
        if (s[i-1]==' '){
            s[i-1]='\0';
        }
    }

    else cout<<"Не введены символы в строке";
    cout<<s;
    getch ();
}
```

Здесь для одной строчки, а для нескольких нужен массив строк.

Comment: Молодой человек, но есть же "сверху" кнопочка для "структурирования" кода. Придайте коду "читабельный" вид - тогда, глядите, спецы по С++ Вам и ответят :) Операцию int User {User--} я Вам не проводил.

Comment: просто отформатировал. @Radik, когда набираете вопрос перед Вами 2 окошка. В верхнем набираете, в нижнем видите, как это будет отображаться. Когда набираете  код программы , то для его форматирования 

1) выделяете его мышкой

2) кликаете в кнопочку "101010" над верхним окошком

Comment: хорошо, буду знать

Comment: Radik, я уже давно не занимался массивами на C++, поэтому подождите. Найду в книге, которую сейчас листаю - отвечу. Если не найду - тогда завтра.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если динамическое выделение требуется, то что-то вроде этого

```
int num_strings = 20; //количество строк    
char ** a = new char* [num_strings]; //массив указателей на строки
for (int i = 0; i < num_strings; i++) {
  a[i] = new char [i*2 + 5];  // здесь выделяем память для строки длиной в квадратных скобках и присваиваем ее адрес элементу массива указателей
  fgets (a[i], i*2+4, stdin); //сразу забываем про потенциально опасную функцию gets и используем безопасную fgets
    //или std::cin.getline (a[i], i*2+4);
}
    for (int i = 0; i < num_strings; i++) 
      std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
```

Comment: Вы молодец. Но что делать, если кол-во строк неизвестно? Конечно, очень хорошо использовать стандартную библиотеку шаблонов :) Но, как я понял, у парня задание не про это. Блин, сам на 2 курсе писал подобное контрольное задание... Уже не помню, жаль.

Comment: Ну так переменная num_strings можно задать в ходе выполнения задания. Если же нужно совсем динамически, то вместо new использовать старую добрую realloc для изменения длины массива указателей. 

И, если это реальное задание, а не учебное, использовать vector или другой подходящий контейнер из STL для хранения указателей на строки.

Comment: Не буду с Вами дальше дискутировать :) У Вас в данный момент голова работает на пару порядков выше, чем у меня. Забыл С++ "консоль" - хоть тресни! Если Вам не трудно, гляньте мой вопрос по поводу сканера штрих-кода, может дадите полезный совет.

Comment: К сожалению, с C# знаком понаслышке.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.А как мне работать с этими строками? Нужно заменить окончания слов ну и уплотнить текст (длины строк одинаковые).

Comment: a[i] - указатель на строку № i. Далее с ней работаете как хотите.

Доступ к символу m в строке n -  a[n][m]

Comment: Вот это, как я понял a[i] = new char [i*2 + 5] это длина строки, с длиной 2, а что значит 5?
Доступ к символу m в строке n - a[n][m], это нужно описать как то, строка у нас это i,так ведь?

Comment: Длина строки в данном примере i*2+5 - взята просто ради примера. Можно любое другое число поставить (кстати, i - это индекс из цикла).

Ничего больше не нужно определять и описывать. Создали строку - обращаетесь к ее символу указанным способом. Только следите, чтобы не заходить за пределы массивов.

Лимит комментариев исчерпан.

Comment: fgets (a[i], i*2+4, stdin) ну вот что значит это комбинация при вводе i*2+4 (2 и 4)? И какая разница между fgets и gets?

Comment: Три отличия функции fgets() от gets():

     -есть второй аргумент – верхний предел;
     -считывает символ новой строки и сохраняет его в строке, в то время, как gets() его отбрасывает;
     -принимает третий аргумент, который указывает на подлежащий считыванию файл.

Comment: Чтобы задать длину строки 15, нужно так вводить код  a[i] = new char [i*2 + 15]?